# Microsoft Access how to stop scrolled text field from returning to top (like scroll-to-top) upon losing focus

Tags: ms-access, vba, scrollbar, ms-access-2016

I'm using Access 2016 in Win 10, everything updated and current.  I have a form with a standard Access TextBox with a vertical scrollbar. All is fine unless I scroll down then click off the field to read info from another source or whatever because the scrolled text rolls right back to the top and I have to scroll back down to where I was before I can resume work. It wastes time and derails my train of thought.

I see no property or method to lock the 'caret' or otherwise disable this annoying behavior. I have also researched everywhere I can think of and no one seems to know what to do about it.

I've even built my own scroll buttons which worked great except it got complicated trying to keep track of the text position if I added or deleted text. So, if someone has a good custom scrollbar in VBA/VB6 I'd love to see it, please.

Thanks for your time and advice. I appreciate it.

Kent in KC.

Comment: AFAIK, no way to control this.

Comment: Maybe use a zoom box to view/edit, review http://www.accessmvp.com/TomvanStiphout/ZoomBox.htm

Comment: For a read only solution you could use an unbound Access webbrowser control, which keeps your position well, and sync its content via VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Set and restore the selected position:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private LastPosition    As Long 

Private Sub YourTextbox_LostFocus()

    LastPosition = Me!YourTextbox.SelStart

End Sub

Private Sub YourTextbox_GotFocus()

    Me!YourTextbox.SelStart = LastPosition
    Me!YourTextbox.SelLength = 0

End Sub

Private Sub Form_Current()

     ' Reset last position.
     LastPosition = 0

End Sub
```

It will scroll the textbox to make the line when left to the top line visible.

Comment: Well, so far, none of these suggestions works satisfactorily, although I appreciate the input. It's surprising to think that someone hasn't already encountered and solved this niggling issue.

Comment: Don't know. My code above is tested and - a bit to my surprise - works quite well for me.

Comment: Thank you, Gustav. You did give me an idea that I've incorporated into a custom scrollbar. It seems to do just what I want but I'm still ironing it out. If it does pan out, I will post the code here.

Again, I really appreciate everyone's help.

Comment: @Gustav: are you sure this code "stops text field from returning to top *upon losing focus*". When I tested it did fix the position of the text in the text field but only *after* it re-gains focus not *upon* loosing it.

Comment: @kent-hartland what was your solution?

Comment: @KentHartland could you post your solution as an answer?

Comment: Big problem with this solution is with larger text, when it gets the focus, Access also scrolls the last line to the top, even though there is plenty of room available to not go scrolling at all. This is something that really bothers/bugs me, as I need to work around the crap autoselection of text on entering (which can only be turned off for everything or nothing, not a specific control).